# Dataframe mean calculation output seems wrong

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean

I am trying to find a mean value of expressed gene, but pandas is giving me a different result than I would expect:

```py
>>> np.mean(dataFrameLiverMean.loc[:,"ENSG00000000003.14"])
-1.708035422500241e-17
>>> dataFrameLiverMean.mean(axis=0)
ENSG00000000003.14    1.067522e-17
# clipped
```

[See results here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Uuq7.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you explain what is the problem you are getting? I didn't understood anything from post

Comment: Post was edited, I have reuploaded the screenshot - the issue will be clear from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mean is pretty much almost zero (10^-17), which is even below the data type's [machine precision](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) (numpy's float 64 has a precission of 2.22044604925e-16).

I think what you're observing is just noise.

Comment: Okay, what bothers me is that one result is positive, and the other one negative. Also, if I do same calculate mean the same way, but selecting particular column first - results are also different:

`dataFrameLiverMean.loc[:,'ENSG00000000003.14'].mean()
-1.708035422500241e-17`

Here pandas is doing the calculation, yet result is different.

Comment: But essentially both results are exactly zero. Given the way computers are built, some operations over numerical data accumulate errors. The magnitude of these errors depend on the data type you are using (e.g. you are using float64, you showed it in the picture you uploaded before).

Comment: Long story short, if you ever obtain a result that is smaller than the machine precision (2.22e-16 for float64), that value is virtually indistinguishable from noise in the computation procedure and you should interpret that value as exactly zero - your machine simply cannot provide a more accurate result. The difference in value is probably given computational routines for obtaining the mean.